# Feedback for a car show t-shirt design competition

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, logo, critique, font-recommendation

So I am designing a T-shirt with a logo for a classic car show in my town. I have attached the design below.

Here are the design guidelines:

**Must include** the words “Orinda Classic Car Show”

**Must include** the year “2023”

**Must include** the depiction of at least one car considered a Land Yacht. (See samples below.) It can include the title “Land Yachts”.

The format must be a high-resolution digital vector file: .ai, .pdf, .psd

It should be sized for 12” x 12“, 300 dpi, and CMYK colors

It will be printed on a black T-shirt.

Your design must be wholly original artwork and can not contain copyrighted material.

Any constructive criticism would be welcome!

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know that I would *ever* use a script typeface around a circle... especially Brush Script. Script type can be difficult to read when it is straight. Overall, the art has a very "vintage" appearance. No idea if that was the intention.

Comment: @Scott - sorry I deleted that, yes, it would need to be CMYK+opaque white. Perhaps they have allowed for that.

Comment: I saw.. so I deleted as well @BillyKerr `:)` TBH CMYK on a black shirt is *really* going to at least need an undercoat. I'd *guess* they don't *really* expect contributors to fully understand the process.

Comment: @Scot - yeah, an opaque white ink layer, left to dry/set, then overprinted with CMYK. Sounds costly.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.